# How to display different screens depending on if the List is empty

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

[image: Screens]

How can i display the screen on the left if there are no Chat List is empty and display the screen on the right, if the Message List is populated.

Comment: return list.isEmpty ? EmptyScreen() : DataScreen() on build method

Comment: @SaiedIslamShuvo what if i want to display a circularprogressindicator before displaying the emptyScreen() ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, we've many solution for this.
U asked about show a circularprogressbar too, right?

So...

```
list.isEmpty 
   ? EmptyScreen() 
   : DataScreen()
```

In EmptyScreen.dart :

```
Future<void> loadingData() async{
  setState(() {isLoading = true;});
  await call_your_loading_data_function();
  setState(() {isLoading = false;});
}
```

and in your layout section of EmptyScreen.dart:

```
(isLoading)
   ? CircularProgressIndicator()
   : Container()
```

You can change Container() by any other component that you want.